# MySQL UPDATE SET field equals to SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I'm trying to update several rows with email addresses. T1.email is to be updated with T2.email based on T1.name existing in T2.name.

Currently, the query looks like this.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.email = T2.email
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
WHERE T1.name = T2.name
AND (Some conditions)
LIMIT 1398
```

A similiar question is asked here, but a syntax error is given.
[SQL UPDATE SET one column to be equal to a value in a related table referenced by a different column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b)

I've also tried updating with ANY.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.email = ANY
    (
        SELECT Table2.email FROM Table2 
        WHERE Table1.accountid = 901234 
        AND Table2.pid = 123 
        AND Table2.email IS NOT NULL 
    )

WHERE Table1.name IN
    (
        SELECT Table2.name FROM Table2
        WHERE Table1.accountid = 19574
        AND Table2.pid = 123 
        AND Table2.email IS NOT NULL
    ) 

LIMIT 1398
```

Currently, this returns an error "SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row".

May be the beginning of a copy and paste job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed under [`UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html), for MySQL you want:

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 USING (name)
SET    T1.email = T2.email
WHERE  (Some conditions)
LIMIT  1398
```