# New email address convention

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a database with email addresses in it.

My company is changing our email address convention from:

first_initiallast_name@mycompany.com

to

first_name.last_name@contoso.com

I'd like to write a SQL statement to update all the email addresses in one shot in this database. First and last name are columns in the same table (we'll call it MY_TABLE for simplicity's sake).

How could I do this in an Oracle SQL statement?

Comment: That's relatively straight-forward to do, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you'd just want

```
UPDATE my_table
   SET email_address = first_name || '.' || last_name || '@contoso.com'
```

That will update every row in the table and assumes that you have no `NULL` first or last name values.

Comment: you will also need to handle space, apostrophe, and potentially other characters in the first_name and last_name.

Comment: Also handle letter's case.

Answer (score 0):

You juste want to update the `email` field with two others fields:

```
UPDATE my_table SET email= first_name || '.' || last_name || '@contoso.com'
    WHERE first_name != NULL AND last_name != NULL
```

Be aware that the transformation might be incorrect if `first_name` or `last_name` is empty...

EDIT: In reality what you want is similar to this question: [SQL UPDATE SET one column to be equal to a value in a related table referenced by a different column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b)