# Copy one column data to another column in same data table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

So here is the problem statement. I have a datatable with two columns BUDGET and ACTUAL. I have a button click event where I want to copy all the budget values to actual values in the same table. I don't want looping and I also tried merge and it did not work. Is there any other approach ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have only one row there is no need to loop. :-)

Comment: where did the data come from, whats the data source?  Also, [Ask]

Comment: @Steve. There are more than thousand rows and there are other columns also

Comment: @Plutonix. The source is a sql server table.

Comment: then clone the column in SQL using an Alias

Comment: I would keep that as the last option. I want to know if there is a way to do in datatable itself

Comment: easiest is sql update like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b

Comment: How about setting the `Expression` property of the ACTUAL column to the value of BUDGET?

Comment: Thanks Josh Part, tat solved it !!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old but I found it looking for something similar, so maybe it still can help someone else. I think the following line would solve it - I'm not sure if Array.ForEach should be considered as a loop in the asker circumstances, what I tried to avoid was writing a For Each loop explicitly.

```
Array.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable().ToArray(), Sub(row) row("ACTUAL") = row("BUDGET"))
```

Based on @Kusal's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822551/how-to-update-column-value-using-linq-query).

Answer (score -1):

There is a built in function in `DataTable` (Copy)

```
DataTable.Copy();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DataTable.Copy() does not copy one column value to another column in same table. Does it ?

Comment: Please check the link you mentioned. It copies the structure and data from one `DataTable` to another. Not from one `DataColumn` to another in the same `DataTable`.