# How to update a table with values coming from another table?

Tags: mysql

I found similar ones at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b), but not exactly the same.

Here is what I need:

I have two tables `a` and `b`, with the following structures:

Table `a`:

```
id  b_id    b_col2 b_col3 col5
1   NULL    NULL   NULL   NULL
2   XXX     XXX    XXX    XXX
```

Table `b`:

```
id    col2 col3
101   ABC  DEF
102   XXX  XXX
```

**UPDATE:** The goal is that with three given inputs `(id, b_id, col5)`, one row of table `a` should be updated accordingly. Specifically, `b_col2` and `b_col3` are extracted from table `b` with that `b.id = b_id`. For example, I want to update the first item of `a` with `b_id`=101 and `col5` = ZZZ. Notice that `b_col2 = ABC` and `b_col3 = DEF` in this case, the updated row should be:

```
id  b_id    b_col2 b_col3 col5
1   101     ABC    DEF    ZZZ
```

I know there is at least a not-so-effective way which I don't like:

```
update a set 
    a.b_id = some-id, 
    a.b_col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM b WHERE b.id = some-id),
    a.b_col3 = (SELECT col3 FROM b WHERE b.id = some-id),
    ...
    where a.`id` = xxx
```

As I said, this is not a very good method, and I am just wondering if there is any better method?

Comment: There's no way to do this, unless you have some shared identifier between the two tables. Otherwise, MySQL has no way of knowing which rows in A go with which rows in B.

Comment: Is `b_id` always offset by 100 from the equivalent `a_id` record?

Comment: Then how do YOU know they are related? Is it by the order they are entered?

Comment: Your question implies that you want to automatically populate the database with equivalent rows. Could you please update your question with the full context so that we can understand and assist you. :)

Comment: @Zwander have updated the question. Hope it's clearer now :)