# SQL Update (selecting on SET)

Tags: sql

I I need to update the Subject for this whole table adding the Post Code each subject.

However, this information is on a 3rd layer table not connected directly to it.
So I have to pass through 1 table to reach the information I need.

Basically is like that

```
Appointments.table > ClientBooking.Table > ClientInfo
```

I tried to link those tables but of course, I need to bring 1 result each time here is is where I lack some knowledge

```
UPDATE Appointments
SET Subject = Subject + (SELECT ZipCode 
                         FROM ClientInfo 
                         INNER JOIN ClientBooking ON ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientBooking.ClientID
                         INNER JOIN Appointments ON ClientBooking.AppointmentID = Appointments.UniqueID
                         WHERE Appointments.UniqueID = "EVERY ID one BY ONe")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL UPDATE SET one column to be equal to a value in a related table referenced by a different column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b)

Answer (score 0):

Just like mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707371/sql-update-set-one-column-to-be-equal-to-a-value-in-a-related-table-referenced-b), can you do this:

```
Update Appointments
set Appointments.Subject = Appointments.Subject + (Select ZipCode from ClientInfo 
                                                   INNER JOIN ClientBooking 
                                                   ON ClientInfo.ClientID = ClientBooking.ClientID
                                                   INNER JOIN Appointments AS App
                                                   ON ClientBooking.AppointmentID = App.UniqueID
                                                   where App.UniqueID = Appointments.UniqueID)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Appointments.UniqueID IN ("comma separated id"). This will bulk update all matching rows and will avoid multiple calls.

Comment: could you exemplify, please?

Comment: Appointments.UniqueID IN (5,10,254). Etc. What is type if UniqueID?

Comment: Oh i see what you mean but doing it i would have to type 10000 Ids by hand.
each appointment has a unique ID

Comment: How are passing all IDs now? In case you want to update all rows of appointment table, then remove the where condition

Comment: I want the query to automatically catch the current Appointment ID he's updating and search for the Post Code

Answer (score -1):

Changed my code for this

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
Update Appointments
set Subject = Appointments.Subject +" - "+ ClientInfo.ZipCode
FROM Appointments
Inner join ClientBooking 
ON Appointments.UniqueID = ClientBooking.AppointmentID
Inner JOIN ClientInfo
ON ClientBooking.ClientID = ClientInfo.ClientID
where Appointments.UniqueID = ClientBooking.AppointmentID
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Now my code works. cheers